# Какой знак препинания поставить? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Перед словом "нормально" какие можно поставить знаки препинания?
Можно ли вообще не ставить?

Предложение:

> Нарушить все договорённости нормально это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Нарушить все договорённости — это нормально?** Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при наличии связки  ЭТО в обязательном порядке.

2) **Нарушить все договорённости — нормально это?** Предложение с именительным темы, также ставится тире.

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63

Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется **личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире:** Тягач — он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко — тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь — она не сладость, дорога в дождь — она беда (Евт.).

Comment: Боюсь, что именительный темы вы сюда напрасно привлекли. 2) от 1) отличается обычной инверсией - и на оба случая все сказанное по поводу тире между подлежащим и сказуемым  распространяются в равной мере.

Comment: По смыслу это действительно только инверсия, но формально слово-связка должно, как я думаю, находиться между подлежащими и сказуемым, иначе грамматика меняется. Вообще говоря, эти темы очень близки, так что  предложения со словами-связками  между подлежащим и сказуемым можно рассматривать как частный случай именительного темы.  Тогда местоимение  ЭТО играет роль подлежащего, стоящего  после именительного темы (И.п.) . Например: Понимать другого человека –  это (И.п.)  особое свойство души. Понимать другого человека –  на это (В.п.) нужно особое свойство души.

Comment: Другие примеры инверсии, когда грамматика меняется: Кататься на лодке - это очень весело. Это очень весело - кататься на лодке (присоединение).

Answer (score 3):

**Нарушить все договорённости — нормально это?**

Я бы поставила тире, основываясь вот на этом правиле:
тире ставится перед словами *это, вот, значит,* стоящими между подлежащим [нарушить] и сказуемым [нормально]. Смущать в этом предложении, как мне кажется, может только нестандартный порядок слов.
[**Все случаи постановки тире**](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200202402)

*А уменьшить сумму человеческих жизней на 50 миллионов лет – это не преступно.*
Е. Замятин. Мы

*Потому что вообще-то не делать то, что ненавидишь, – это нормально.*
М. Лоренц. Все объясняет

Comment: Здесь использована инверсия, которая меняет грамматическую конструкцию. О необходимости  такой инверсии сложно говорить без контекста, но автор должен понимать, зачем ему нестандартный порядок слов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поставить [многоточие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5), [двоеточие](http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/9-klass/bessoiuznye-slozhnye-predlozheniia-11388/dvoetochie-v-bessoiuznykh-slozhnykh-predlozheniiakh-11998/re-ba1e5543-863c-45d5-a68c-f3bd3c9df0ed) (особенно если речь о заголовке или если в предложении есть оттенок смысла "то есть это нормально, по-вашему?") или [тире](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire).

Отсутствие знака было бы ошибкой, поскольку речь о сложном (но не распространенном) предложении, на основании чего возможен и вариант с двоеточием в том числе.

Comment: а без знака будет ошибкой?

Comment: Это вопрос к Розенталю или Лопатину.

Comment: Многоточие прикольно выглядит, а мне даже в голову не приходило. Двоеточие по меньшей мере странно будет...

Comment: Без знака было бы ошибкой, а двоеточие - это частный случай сложного (но не распространенного) предложения.